Undefined Array Key for PHP display code from HTML forms
I want to create an html code that submits a form into a PHP file, this is the file:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Add New Patient</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Ryufath">
    <meta name="description" content="Our Official Restaurant Site">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    <style>
        /* General styles for the entire page */
        html {
            background-color: white;
        }

        /* Header styles */
        header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            color: white;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #14d8a7;
            z-index: 1000; /* Ensure the header is on top of other elements */
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-top: 35px;
            padding-bottom: 35px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 20%;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        footer {
            padding: 10px;
            size: 5px;
            background-color: #14d8a7;
            color: white;
        }

        /* Navigation styles */
        .nav__links {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .nav__links li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .nav__links li a {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: color 0.3s ease;
        }

        .nav__links li a:hover {
            color: #ffff4d;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #4D4D4F;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ffff4d;
            color: black;
        }

        .nav__links li:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        .Home {
            width: 3%;
            height: 3%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 32px;
            left: 6px;
        }

        /* Form styles */
        .form-container {
            margin: 100px auto;
            width: 60%;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #14d8a7;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }

        .form-container h2 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #14d8a7;
        }

        .form-container label {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px 0 5px;
            color: #333;
        }

        .form-container input,
        .form-container select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        .form-container .tel-container {
            display: flex;
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .form-container .tel-container select {
            width: 30%;
        }

        .form-container .tel-container input {
            width: 70%;
        }

        .form-container button {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #14d8a7;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .form-container button:hover {
            background-color: #0ebd95;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img class="Home" src="C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\237-2378542_icon-symbol-gui-house-home-start-top-check-removebg-preview.png">
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav__links">
                <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Patient Management</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="AddNewPatient.html">Add New Patient</a>
                        <a href="http://localhost/php-projects/Patient.php">Find & Search Patient</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Appointments.html">Appointments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Medication Management</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="MedicationList.html">Medication List</a>
                        <a href="AddMedication.html">Add Medication</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Book</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="form-container">
            <h2>Fill in Your Details</h2>
            <form action="http://localhost/php-projects/Patient.php" method="post">
                <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required>

                <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
                <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" required>

                <label for="birthplace">Birth Place</label>
                <input type="text" id="birthplace" name="birthplace" required>

                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                <select id="gender" name="gender" required>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>

                <label for="tel">Telephone Number</label>
                <div class="tel-container">
                    <select id="telcode" name="telcode" required>
                        <option value="+1">+1</option>
                        <option value="+44">+44</option>
                        <option value="+61">+61</option>
                        <option value="+91">+91</option>
                        <!-- Add more options as needed -->
                    </select>
                    <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" required>
                </div>

                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>All Rights Reserved (c)</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>


Then, I wrote that php file to display the results from the forms. Note that this can be seen from the XAAMP that I have:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mentcare IS - View Patients</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Ryufath">
    <meta name="description" content="Our Official Patient Management Site">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    <style>
        /* General styles for the entire page */
        html {
            background-color: white;
        }

        /* Header styles */
        header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            color: white;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #14d8a7;
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-top: 35px;
            padding-bottom: 35px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 20%;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        footer {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #14d8a7;
            color: white;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /* Navigation styles */
        .nav__links {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .nav__links li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 20px;
            position: relative; /* Needed for the dropdown */
        }

        .nav__links li a {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white; /* Header text color*/
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: color 0.3s ease;
        }

        .nav__links li a:hover {
            color: #ffff4d;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #4D4D4F;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ffff4d;
            color: black;
        }

        .nav__links li:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        .Home {
            width: 4%;
            height: 4%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 32px;
            left: 15px;
        }

        /* Table styles */
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 80px 0 20px;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            text-align: left;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 12px;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img class="Home" src="C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\237-2378542_icon-symbol-gui-house-home-start-top-check-removebg-preview.png">
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav__links">
                <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Patient Management</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="AddNewPatient.html">Add New Patient</a>
                        <a href="Patients.php">Find & Search Patient</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Appointments.html">Appointments</a></li> <!-- It will lead directly to calendar-->
                <li><a href="#">Medication Management</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="MedicationList.html">Medication List</a>
                        <a href="AddMedication.html">Add Medication</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Book</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Patient ID</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Birth Place</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        // Database connection details
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "pass"; 
        $dbname = "MentcareDB";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Fetch data from the 'patients' table
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // Output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>
                        <td>" . $row["patient_id"] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["full_name"] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["date_of_birth"] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["birth_place"] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["gender"] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["telephone_code"] . " " . $row["telephone_number"] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row["email"] . "</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td colspan='7'>No records found</td></tr>";
        }

        // Close connection
        $conn->close();
        ?>

    </table>
</main>


    <footer>
        <p>All Rights Reserved (c)</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>


For some reason, it keeps showing

Warning: Undefined array key "fullname" in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-projects\Patient.php

on line 20.
Please help me fix it

I think you are facing issue in Patient.php where you have written submission logic and query. Please share code of that file as well and also write your MySQL table structure i.e., table name, column names.

check file C:\xampp\htdocs\php-projects\Patient.php, maybe it should be ["full_name"] ?

You are submitting the data to MySQL, not to phpmyadmin. The latter is a database administration tool. You also need to edit the post and remove irrelevant stuff - I am certain that all your inline CSS is not required to help someone duplicate the problem.

As above, we can't diagnose an error in patient.php without seeing the code for that script. Please edit the question to include that, without any irrelevant stuff.

you are sending "fullname" from the form and trying to display as  $row["full_name"]. I am sure you are having issue with this, please check the field you are sending in request and trying to display.

No, $row["full_name"] is from the database. Look more carefully at the code. We can't see the script which processes the form- that has already been pointed out in the other comments

i know there is no processing script but the thing is he is sending request with diffrent name and trying to access with different name, usually we run into issue while having diffrent name for the same thing. maybe my answer was not clear enough but my  point was when your forms has diffrent filed name in request , you might end up doing typo.

Your answer was clear, but it's wrong. Look at the code. This code does not try to read from the form data, it reads from the database. And it does not attempt to read a field called "fullname". So it's not relevant to the error, the code we can see physically cannot produce the reported error

@ADyson please check the lines where he says "Then, I wrote that php file to display the results from the forms. Note that this can be seen from the XAAMP that I have:" so when the things he shared is incomplete i can only make guess and you too can . so i am aksing him to check the processing i.e Patient.php where he is sending the value from the form. I hope you know what he is asking but i answered what was in the context. By the way you havent answered it either nor you have given context. just saying my answer is wrong is not going to help the person who asked question.

We need to see the context before we answer, not just guess. Guessing is not a good use of time. And anyway you specifically said that $row["full_name"] causes the error, which is a) from the current code not some other code and b) is clearly incorrect because $row is from the database not the form, and because a request to show a field called "full_name" cannot cause an error that "fullname" is missing. This is a simple and obvious fact.

And the OP may have written Then, I wrote that php file to display the results from the forms. Note that this can be seen from the XAAMP that I have...but it is clear from looking at the code that this is not true because none of the provided code tries to read anything from a form

so what is your idea  of having undefined array key , what i understand is that array key is not present . he might have saved in the db with "fullname" filed and trying to get it with   $row["full_name"]  so when the column name does not match are we not likely to get this error ?? or am i too slow to understand that.

And anyway the post is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr - this error is well understood and well documented, its doubtful that new answers will add anything

he might have saved in the db with "fullname" filed and trying to get it with $row["full_name"] ...if so that would produce the error "undefined array key full_name" not "undefined array key fullname". So that cannot be the problem, as I've explained several times already.

Also the line of code you're saying caused the problem is quite obviously not on line 20 of the file shown (as reported by the error message). So it simply cannot be the right place, for multiple reasons. You don't appear to have applied any logic when making your suggestion.

i think you are still not getting my point , you dont get the context at all, you are too into the code. I am just giving a context  and you are arguing over the answer which you too dont have . ok you win i lose , you are too smart to solve everything . keep up the good work.

I don't have the exact answer, because only I can't see the code which is causing the error. Neither can you, and therefore you also do not have the answer. Your answer is completely wrong, because 1) The code $row["full_name"] has nothing to do with processing a form, which is where the OP said the error is happening 2) that code tries to read a "full_name" field, but the error is saying it can't find the "fullname" field. Since that line is not trying to read the "fullname" field, it's impossible that it would complain about "fullname" not existing. This is simple logic!

I am just giving a context...yes, but it's a provably incorrect context. You are too into the code...what on earth do you mean? The code is the whole point of questions on stackoverflow. If we're not talking about code then why are we here?? ok you win i lose...nobody loses, it's just a wrong answer, which you can delete whenever you like. I only tried to help you avoid too many downvotes by pointing out that the answer is wrong, so you can remove it. But for some reason you tried to have an argument even when I explained that it's incorrect. We all make mistakes, there's no shame.

Just to round off with some hard evidence: If the field is called "full_name" in the database then it doesn't crash- which is what's happening in the OP's code, because that line is not producing an error - demo: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/3f2064dcab1ba680c449e9eabc03d8f9/php/php81/f7fe6aace9779ba873a9d34716f59111/ . But if the field is called "fullname" in the database, as per your guess, then it produces the error "undefined array key full_name". Demo: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/916aa1f1369e2f6f09d46cc6e4b149c7/php/php81/f7fe6aace9779ba873a9d34716f59111/  ...

... Note that this is not the same as the error the OP mentions in the question. The error the OP states could only be caused in this code if the scenario was the opposite way round - e.g. if the field in the DB is called full_name and the code tries to select $row["fullname"] - demo:  https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/3f2064dcab1ba680c449e9eabc03d8f9/php/php81/d63ac01ff7fdc0279ef8800448b11ae7/ . But that is not what the OP's code is doing, and therefore that line $row["full_name"] cannot be the source of the reported error.

@ADyson i never concretely said $row["full_name"] was the line causing the error, i said "please check the field you are sending in request and trying to display" and i did mention about the typo earlier saying if my explanation was not clear enough "maybe my answer was not clear enough but my point was when your forms has diffrent filed name in request , you might end up doing typo.". as we dont have the Patient.php and database schema all i wanted was to ask him check all the place where the field is suppose to be. if suggesting someone to  what to look is wrong then , ok i am wrong.

I am sure you are having issue with this looks to me like you're telling the OP that's the source of the error. And if it's not, then why even mention it? "please check the field you are sending in request and trying to display...yes, but as I've said repeatedly, the code the OP has shown has nothing to do with any field sent in any request, it is fetching from the database. So it has no relationship to the field name sent in the form. And it cannot cause the stated error anyway because asking for "full_name" never makes it complain about "fullname" being missing!

if suggesting someone to what to look is wrong...but why would you suggest to look there? It makes no logical sense whatsoever - see my explanation above.

as we dont have the Patient.php and database schema all i wanted was to ask him check all the place where the field is suppose to be ...yeah, but a) we know the error is in patient.php, because the error message says so. And b) we know the error is on line 20 because the error message says it, so even if the code shown is actually from patient.php, there's no possible way that <td>" . $row["full_name"] . "</td> could ever be line 20, since there is so much code above it already. And c) again, code asking for "full_name" cannot ever produce an error complaining that "fullname" is missing!

There is no logical reason of any sort for suggesting the OP to look at the line of code you mentioned. Nothing in the code, the error message or the OP's description suggests any link to that line of code at all. I've proved this from every possible angle, multiple times in this discussion, and yet you're still arguing with me, and without providing a single piece of provable evidence to the contrary, or giving any sensible reason (I don't count guesswork as a sensible reason!) as to why you ever made the suggestion. I am, quite genuinely, baffled by such an attitude.

because if you check the fullname filed from form  you will follow where it goes from there > there is a post request to  Patient.php > now we need to check there how the request is processed there and stored in the db , i think if he does that he could find what is wrong, i was just trying to tell the context how to check the issue. By the way you are only genius here with spot on answer so i know my answer is invalid and gets downvote. sorry for my lame explanation again. i am amazed how fast stackoverflow started being place only for genius.

and one last thing , i asked him to check " . $row["full_name"] . " because most often when you see the disparity in fields name then its most likely typo . therfore i think i mentioned you that in my first reply to you.

because most often when you see the disparity in fields name then its most likely typo...I don't dispute that a typo is a possible reason for the error the OP told us about. But there's no logic at all for mentioning that particular line of code, for all the reasons I've been over. That line cannot possibly cause the stated error, in any circumstance.

i refernced that line to compare with the form filed as they have disparity , which can also be present in the Patient.php file or the db schema. i was just trying to refernece the disparity that might have occured , therfore i wanted him to go throught the flow  from form > php file >  database to identify the issue. anyway you are the master so this is it from my side. Thank you for your insight aswell.

You're not listening, are you. One last time: that line of code has nothing to do with the form, it only reads from the database, not the form. That line of code cannot cause undefined array key fullname because it is not trying to access a field called "fullname". So if you think there is a disparity compared to the form, there is no possible way this could be a relevant place to look

you must be hurt because of how i replied you. i never said that line is causing the error. i was showing the disparity of refernecing the same filed with different name. when you do that you are most likely to make typo in your code or while defining the db schema. so my only point is to show how to check the issue from the the FE > BE > DB. I think you might need specific and detail answer but everyone needs to learn how to debug and fix their code and not rely on people like you who cannot understand the context and stick with "that line is not producing error" , if i am wrong ,answer right

i never said that line is causing the error...you strongly implied it. You said you are sending "fullname" from the form and trying to display as $row["full_name"]...suggesting a strong (but non-existent in reality!) causal link. And if you didn't think it causes the error, there's no point mentioning it in an answer. I'm not hurt, I don't take this stuff personally! It's just a technical discussion. I am a little confused as to why you cannot see or acknowledge - in the face of the clear evidence - that what you suggested does not make any sense, but that's all.

my only point is to show how to check the issue...by suggesting the OP look somewhere which clearly has no relationship to the issue at all. This is just a distraction and total waste of time for the OP. everyone needs to learn how to debug...yep, that's true. But if you had any good idea of how to do that you would not have made the suggestion to look at $row["full_name"]. Other than that, your suggestion to "check the field you are sending" doesn't give the OP any practical information on how to actually do that, so they are no further forward.

if i am wrong ,answer right...wow, we're still on that one. Last time: we cannot say for certain what the exact issue is, because we cannot see the code which caused the error, because the OP did not provide it. But, unlike your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr explains in general what causes "undefined array key" errors, and how to look for the root causes. So the OP can then go and check their code. Or they can share Patient.php with us here, and we can look again. Until then, there is no other answer

cannot understand the context...no idea what you mean by this. Which context have I missed? You wrote a two-sentence answer in which the first sentence suggests an incorrect and completely irrelevant place to look for the error, and a second sentence which is so vague it's of no real value to anyone reading it. What other "context" can anyone derive?

Anyway, we are going round in circles because you won't acknowledge the facts, so I won't be making any further comment on this nonsense. Your answer is incorrect, my demo links prove that. I tried to help you understand why it was wrong so you could correct your post or remove it, but you tried to shout me down with gibberish instead. And that's really all there is to it. Have a great day.
